# mod_rewrite http/https for robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, robots.txt

Is there a way to rewrite the path/filename for the robots.txt?

In my docroot, i placed `robots.txt` and a `robots_ssl.txt`. Now I want to "redirect" the bot, depending on which site he is actually visiting. I made a rule in my `.htaccess` which reads as followed:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots_ssl.txt [L]
```

To see the diffrence, I added a comment on top of both of the files. When I'm calling https://example.com/robots.txt it should display a txt-file with the comment:

*robots.txt for https*

otherwise, in case of http:

*robots.txt for http*

Any ideas how to solve the problem? Is my RewriteCond wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule for serving a SSL specific `robots.txt`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots_ssl.txt [L,NC]
```